# Prisma use 'include' to query, but compile error

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

Prisma use 'include' to join query, but compile error

```
const user = await db.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        uid: req.uid
      },
      include: {
        characters: true
      }
    });

    ctx.body = {
      user: user,
      characters: user?.characters
    };
```

schema.prisma

```
model Character {
  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @unique
  name      String 
  des       String?  
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [uid], onDelete: Cascade)
  userId    String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@unique([userId, name])
}

model User {
  id    Int      @default(autoincrement()) @unique
  uid        String   @id @default(nanoid())
  name         String?        @unique
  avatar       String?
  openId       String?
  conversations Conversation[]
  characters Character[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

My code passes static type checking in VS Code, but I encounter errors when running it with ts-node.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

error stack

```
src/index.ts:820
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
source-map-support.js:590
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
controller/api/user.ts(21,25): error TS2339: Property 'characters' does not exist on type '{} & { id: number; uid: string; name: string | null; avatar: string | null; openId: string | null; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }'.
```